# having trouble to load data using multiple query with different table dynamically in hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-6.x

what is the best way to get data from multiple query with different table dynamically in hibernate 6. Say for example, I have to get data from below queries from hibernate. The selection for one or more query is dynamic. What is the best way to write this using hibernate 6 as it enforce to have an entity.

```
select country, desc from table1;
select country, desc from table2;
select country, desc from table3;
...
```

Hibernate 6 is enforcing entity for each of the query, but in my case the are many tables involved. Not sure the best way to deal with this.

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you want to achieve and what your problem with entities is. You can fetch select results into either an entity or a DTO-projection, but I don't know if this distinction is related to your doubts.